# URLDecoderUtil class is removed from struts2-core 6.3.0.2 version. What is the alternative for this class in the latest versions?

Tags: java, struts2, struts-tags, versionupgrade

`URLDecoderUtil (org.apache.struts2.util.URLDecoderUtil)` class is removed from struts2-core 6.3.0.2 version. What is the alternative for this class in the latest versions?

Found an alternative `URLDecoder class (org.apache.struts2.url.URLDecoder)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`StrutsUrlDecoder`](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/url/StrutsUrlDecoder.java). It is responsible for
decoding a `x-www-form-urlencoded` string and query string.

It implements `UrlDecoder` interface.

> URL Decoder used internally by Struts
>
> - @since Struts 6.1.0